# estoy usando la pasarela de pago de stripe en proyecto angular como frontend y express como backend

Tags: angular, express, stripe

estoy utilizando stripe para una pasarela de pago con diferentes metodos de pago, pero al momento de enviar los datos en consola me marca el siguiente error

```
app.component.ts:78 Error al confirmar el pago: IntegrationError: Invalid value for confirmCardPayment: payment_method.card was `payment` Element, which cannot be used to create card PaymentMethods.
at v3/:1:468793
at ne (v3/:1:158886)
at v3/:1:472508
at ne (v3/:1:158886)
at re (v3/:1:159141)
at h (v3/:1:461796)
at v3/:1:321383
at v3/:1:136439
at e.<anonymous> (v3/:1:368156)
at e.confirmCardPayment (v3/:1:81334)
```

este es mi codigo TypeScript de mi componente

```
    import { AfterViewInit, Component} from '@angular/core';
import { StripeService } from './stripe.service';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  paymentError: string = '';
  paymentSuccess: boolean = false;
  stripe: any;
  paymentElement: any;
  addressElement: any;
  clientSecret: any; 
  

  constructor(private stripeService: StripeService) {}

  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    try {
      this.stripe = await loadStripe('public_Key'); // Reemplaza con tu clave pública de Stripe
      const response: any = await this.stripeService.createPaymentIntent(100).toPromise();
      this.clientSecret = response.clientSecret;
      const appearance = {
        theme: 'flat',
        variables: { colorPrimaryText: '#262626' }
      };
      const options = {
        layout: {
        type: 'tabs',
        defaultCollapsed: false,
      }
      };

            
      const elements = this.stripe.elements({
        clientSecret: this.clientSecret,
        
      });
      
      // this.addressElement = elements.create('address', options);
      this.paymentElement = elements.create('payment', options);

      // this.addressElement.mount('#address-element');
      this.paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');


    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al inicializar Stripe:', error);
    }
  }

  async onSubmit() {
    try {
      const { paymentIntent, error } = await this.stripe.confirmCardPayment(this.clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: this.paymentElement
        }
      });

      if (paymentIntent) {
        // Pago confirmado, haz algo con paymentIntent
        console.log('Pago confirmado. Detalles:', paymentIntent);
        // Por ejemplo, puedes redirigir al usuario a una página de confirmación
        this.paymentSuccess = true;
      } else if (error) {
        // Error al procesar el pago, haz algo con error
        
        
      console.error('Error al procesar el pago:', error);
      // Puedes mostrar un mensaje de error al usuario
      this.paymentError = 'Hubo un error al procesar el pago. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde.';
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al confirmar el pago:', error);
      // Puedes manejar errores generales aquí
      this.paymentError = 'Hubo un error al confirmar el pago. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde.';
    }
  }
}
```

este es el servicio

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StripeService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  createPaymentIntent(amount: number) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/pay/create-payment-intent`, { amount });
  }  


}
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StripeService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  createPaymentIntent(amount: number) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/pay/create-payment-intent`, { amount });
  }  


}
```

codigo backend express

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const { default: Stripe } = require('stripe');
var stripe = require('stripe')('Secret_Key');

//Alta
router.post('/create-payment-intent', async(req,res)=>{
    const { amount } = req.body;
    const { payment_method_id } = req.body;
    try {
        const cantidadMx = Math.round(amount * 100);
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
          payment_method: payment_method_id,
          amount: cantidadMx,
          currency: 'mxn', 
          automatic_payment_methods: { enabled: true },
          description: 'hola'
        });
        res.send({
          clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
          
        });
      }catch (e) {
        return res.status(400).send({
          error: {
            message: e.message,
          },
        });
      }
      
    });
  

module.exports = router;

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const { default: Stripe } = require('stripe');
var stripe = require('stripe')('Secret_Key');

//Alta
router.post('/create-payment-intent', async(req,res)=>{
    const { amount } = req.body;
    const { payment_method_id } = req.body;
    try {
        const cantidadMx = Math.round(amount * 100);
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
          payment_method: payment_method_id,
          amount: cantidadMx,
          currency: 'mxn', 
          automatic_payment_methods: { enabled: true },
          description: 'hola'
        });
        res.send({
          clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
          
        });
      }catch (e) {
        return res.status(400).send({
          error: {
            message: e.message,
          },
        });
      }
      
    });
  

    

module.exports = router;
```

tengo configurado el corss y todo lo necesario para las peticiones, de hecho el pago llega al dashboard de stripe pero aparece incompleto por que no tiene metodo de pago, y auque seleccione oxxo o tarjeta o googlepay no me los detecta

Ayuda a resolverlo porfavor

Comment: Prueba a darle un tipo de dato a todo en lugar de usar `any`, tal vez el error así sea más especifico.